# How to get a fraction number (float )

Tags: scala

Any idea why scala interpreter is giving this result instead of 3.5

```
println(7/2)

3
```

How to get 3.5 for above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types. `7` and `2` are `Int` and the result type is inferred as `Int`. Changing one of them to a double and the types are inferred as `Double` and you get the decimal value `3.5`.

```
scala> 7 / 2.0
res0: Double = 3.5
```